# Mysql escaping recount integers in REPLACE

Tags: mysql

I have a replace statement to replace numerical values in columns with text, the text may contain numbers, how to avoid re-replacing these numbers?

```
update 
`obsmaintble` 
set
`obsvteduration` = REPLACE(`obsvteduration`, '0', 'No C-Section'), 
`obsvteduration` = REPLACE(`obsvteduration`, '1', 'LOS equal or more than \4 - Given up to discharge'), 
`obsvteduration` = REPLACE(`obsvteduration`, '2', 'LOS equal or more than \4 - Given for < \4 days'),
`obsvteduration` = REPLACE(`obsvteduration`, '3', 'LOS less than \4 Given up to discharge'), 
`obsvteduration` = REPLACE(`obsvteduration`, '4', 'Not given'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Is there other way?
I have other statements with different numbers...

Comment: I can't think of a good way in ordinary SQL. It might be better to do it in another language, which way have a function like PHP's `str_replace()` that can do multiple replacements simultaneously.